# Does JsonNode.at(JsonPointer) expect relative or absolute paths?

Tags: jackson

Per https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/228#issuecomment-156159231 Json nodes do not contain references to their parents.

JsonPointer paths reference nodes in terms of an absolute path from the root of a JSON document.

Given this fact, how can JsonNode.at(JsonPointer) return the right node when it is invoked on a non-root node?

For example, given:

```
{
  "parent":
  {
    "child": "foobar"
  }
}
```

If we invoke `JsonNode.at(JsonPointer)` where `JsonNode` is the child node and the desired path is "/parent", I can't see a way for Jackson returning the correct value. Even if we pass in the desired path of "/parent/child" Jackson would need to keep track of the path of the current node, which it does not seem to do.

Does this mean that `JsonNode.at(JsonPointer)` interprets the path as being relative to the node it is invoked on, as opposed to relative to the root node?